# for loop first statement should be declaration

Tags: c

```
main ()
{
      char i = 0;
      for (i <= 5 && i >= -1; ++i; i > 0)
          printf ("%d", i);
      getch ();
}
```

I am a Java student and recently I started doing C programs. I saw this question in a C book. I have the following doubts about this program:

1. This  program compiles well. Should this not cause a compiler error? The first part of the for loop should be a declaration but here it is a boolean expression.
2. The output is `1,2,3,4.....126,127,-128....-2,-1`. Why does the output stop at -1? This should be an infinite series, repeating the above series forever.

Comment: Compiling well? I'll eat my shoe if this compiles well.

Comment: I'll eat my dog if this compiles well.

Comment: No chance of error free compilation.

Comment: I'll eat my Compiler if this compiles well.

Comment: I'll eat my boss anyway.

Comment: /me edits the post and laughs hysterically while others eat their stuff

Comment: My boss will eat me if i tell this compiles.

Comment: Doesn't compile under VS2008.

Comment: Does it compile if `i>=-` is changed to something "sensible" like `i>=2`?

Comment: Disagree with close. It is clear what the question is asking, even though it is written in slightly broken English.

Comment: @immibis you are right. It should have been closed as "could not be reproduced"

Comment: @JanDvorak Or possibly should not ;-) Anyway I think this question deserves an answer, because it might be quite instructive (including the UB present :-) )

Comment: So then be ready to eat your boss  or your shoes whatever you want.This is true that i forgot to include   i>=-1.But it is well understood that their is something if i am saying this program is compiling and also i am providing you output.Instead of make fun of unrelevent mistakes or laugh you should understand code and should post answer.If still someone says i will eat boss or shoes etc .then pick up "Test your c skills "By yashwant kanetkar 2nd edition page number50 question number2.7.other wise type this question and watch..

Comment: @user3335653 Eh the answer is simple, even though I cannot currently post it. Basically for loop isn't limited to (declaration; condition; increment), but to (expression; expression; expression), which are then put into the proper places for the loop (first expression is put outside the loop itself, it is sort of a loop preparation, second expression is put as first thing in the loop, if it evaluates to false, loop ends;, third expression is put as the last thing that happens in the loop.) The reason it terminates is that ++i returns 0 at one point, which evaluates to false, ending the loop.

Comment: @user3335653 Oh and since char on your platform is signed, its overflow invokes UB, which is bad, evil, sucky, and will break when you least expect it. ;-)

Comment: @Xarn can you please tell what is UB

Comment: Apart from being nonsense this progam compiles here (with a warning). I wonder from which book he took this example, maybe it was just to demonstrate what kind of nonsense you can write in C. Disagree also with closing the question.

Comment: @user3335653 It means that what happens is not defined, doesn't have to be consistent and if the program invoking it steals your credit card details, hires assassins to kill you and your family, formats your harddrive, etc, it is entirely correct in doing so. :-D Note, this is in contrast with implementation-defined behaviour, which means that a compiler decides, but has to decide consistently. This is invoked with code like `int a = foo() + bar()`, where it depends on compiler whether it first calls `foo` or `bar`.

Comment: ... and happy shoe eating BTW.

Comment: @user3335653 It means the C standard doesn't say what will happen. It doesn't mean that it does random things, and it doesn't mean that it will be inconsistent. It means the standard doesn't guarantee anything. In practice, most compilers will make your char wrap around unless optimizations are turned on (if optimizations *are* turned on, practical results *will* be random and inconsistent).

Comment: Those who commented before the question was edited must be eating their words now :)

Comment: @ajay Seeing how all the answers just restated my comments (note, I do not say that they took the answer from them, just that they are the correct answer), not really. ;-)

Comment: @Xarn after revision 3, sure, but all the (correct) comments about it not compiling were posted when `-1` was just the `-`. Please check the revision history before criticising people for saying something clearly doesn't compile when it clearly does when it's not what they're saying doesn't compile.

Comment: @JanDvorak If the changes to make it compile are trivial (include proper header, fix obvious typo) and don't have anything to do with the question proper, I would expect people to work with it. Oh and the revision history is actually showing compilable version as the first rev. (Which is weird, since it wasn't so...)

Comment: @Xarn It's hard to tell as "obvious typo", especially in questions. Also, never assume some typo is due to a transcription error rather than due to being in OP's code. Here, the code isn't OP's, but its' still not obvious what is the correct fix (every numeric literal is a valid fix here, providing at least 20 plausible fixes (-9..9, '-')). `0` is especially plausible (and with very different effects from `-1`) because they are neigboring keys on the QWERTY keyboard.

Comment: @Jan Dvorak .Sir Look it is true that there was an error but Do you really think that error was relevent or when i am posting that it is compiling and also i am posting output is it not well understood that there is something after i>-.if you are saying that one question should be closed because it has some irrelevent error than i think this question should also be closed even now because i have not included header files yet.

Comment: @JanDvorak Actually, any of the possible fixes was valid and would have the same effect, as that expression is side-effect free and any sane compiler will throw it out. And if the typo is part of the OP problem, point it out, don't go "won't compile, won't answer".

Comment: @user3335653 two points here: if you have a typo in your question, it's always valid to comment upon it. Also, it wasn't entirely clear if it was a typo or straight up invalid code with made up results. It is also a valid close reason. If the code gets fixed subsequently (as happened here), it may be reopened (as happened here) and gather further positive votes (as happened here). Such fix doesn't invalidate any comments preceding the fix. It only makes them obsolete.

Comment: @Xarn noted, sorry. The comments were indeed not very constructive. The closure before R3 was still entirely valid, as was the reopening after R3 was posted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(Some people are going to have to eat some weird stuff now)

When compiling with GCC-4.8.1 on MinGW32 (flags: `-Wall -pedantic -std=c99`) I get only the following warnings:

```
In function 'main':
6:7: warning: statement with no effect [-Wunused-value]
       for (i <= 5 && i >= -1; ++i; i > 0)
       ^
6:7: warning: statement with no effect [-Wunused-value]
```

This can be explained as follows. As mentioned in the comments, the syntax for a `for`-loop is just `for(expression-1; expression-2; expression-3)` (where each of the expressions can also be empty). Moreover the `for`-loop can be viewed as just syntactic-sugar for a `while`-loop and it is indeed translatable to:

```
expression-1;
while(expression-2){
    body;
    expression-3;
}
```

In your case it translates to:

```
i <= 5 && i >= -1;
while (++i) {
    printf ("%d", i);
    i > 0;
}
```

GCC then warns about expression-1 and expression-3 since they valid and produce a value, but the value is discarded and the expressions have no side-effects. When optimizing the compiler will probably not even include these expressions in the generated code since they have no effect.

The reason it doesn't loop forever is because eventually `++i` will overflow and the compiler/platform/the gnomes in the machine have decided to make it wrap around so that it becomes negative and eventually goes back up to 0: stopping the loop. Note that this is strictly speaking undefined-behaviour since it invokes signed-integer-overflow.

Comment: Ouch at that last snippet. (fix it and pretend you didn't take it from the other answer ;-) ). Also shouldn't overflow of any signed integral type be undefined?

Comment: +1 for the first line of your answer :) SO needs humor sometimes :)

Comment: @Xarn Eek! You caught me! Fixed ;)

Comment: @Kninnug I am always watching. :-D (Actually I tried to edit the answer with the error and seeing it jump out again was just weird.)

Comment: The signedness of `char` is implementation-defined. If `char` is equivalent to `uint8_t` on the given machine, then the overflow is well-defined. If `char` is equivalent to `int8_t`, then the overflow is undefined behavior

Comment: "(Some people are going to have to eat some weird stuff now)" -  whey won't. The comments were posted against the R1/R2 of this question, which didn't include the `1` in `-1`.

Answer (score 6):

For loop is composed of three expressions, so this example compiles well. The first one is `i <= 5 && i >= -1`. It is doing nothing. The second one is the condition when the cycle shall stop. In your case `++i` means that the cycle stops when `i` reaches the value 0. The third part `i>0` does nothing. So your cycle:

```
  for (i <= 5 && i >= -1; ++i; i > 0)
      printf ("%d", i);
```

is equivalent to:

```
  i <= 5 && i >= -1;
  while (++i) {
      printf ("%d", i);
      i>0;
  }
```

which is equivalent to:

```
  while (++i) {
      printf ("%d", i);
  }
```

Answer (score 3):

1. The first part can be any valid C expression. It can even be left blank. It is custom to use it to assign an initial value to the loop variable, though.
2. A `char` overflows pretty quickly, and when the value of the second expression, `++i` reaches `0` the loop stops.